# How do I setup nginx on a nuxt.js website preferably on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, nuxt.js

I am having a problem setting up nginx on a webserver. 
I am deploying my application on Heroku and I need to have nginx infront of nuxt.js.
The docs say a little on how to use nginx on nuxt but only a little. They describe a
conf file but they do not state where to put the conf file. And then they go all the way to Laravel. 
I am using node.js and vue.js and I turned to nuxt.js thinking it was easier to set up nginx on it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK.
Finally, after giving up 5 times I have set up nuxt.js with nginx heroku buildpack.
For those who are interested in how I did it checkout this repository.
https://github.com/rsgilbert/hellonuxt.

In there you will find a file called [hellonuxt-steps](https://github.com/rsgilbert/hellonuxt/blob/master/hellonuxt-steps) that covers all the steps I took. From creating the nuxt app to deploying and then to setting up nginx and redeploying. You can benefit even though you are not using nuxt.

These are some of the important webpages I visited that really helped me understand what's happening and how to set up nginx:

[Have you managed to make your node nginx proxy setup on Heroku work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745308/have-you-managed-to-make-your-node-nginx-proxy-setup-on-heroku-work)

[Heroku + Node (Parse server) + nginx not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787420/heroku-node-parse-server-nginx-not-working)

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/beanieboi/nginx-buildpack

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx

The last one was really annoying. For instance, they say "You touch /tmp/app-initialized when you are ready for traffic" ?? What's touch?